# latexmkrc custom dependency code to generate syi file

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, latexmk, makeindex, nomencl

I am using the excellent `latexmk` build tool to build a PhD thesis based on 
the template:
https://github.com/holgern/TUB_PhDThesisTemplate

Project requires me to manually specify a makeindex command for generating the abbreviations/glossaries/symbols. Following instructions at read-the-docs website of latexmk, I defined a `customdependency` code-block in my `latexmkrc` config to obtain the required gls file. This works fine.

```
@cus_dep_list = (@cus_dep_list, "glo-abr gls-abr 0 makenomenclature");
sub makenomenclature {
   system("makeindex $_[0].glo-abr -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].gls-abr"); }
@generated_exts = (@generated_exts, 'glo-abr');
```

However, the problem is right now the following. The project requires me to generate an `syi` file. I tried the above technique, but this does not work at all, i.e. the `syi` file is not produced. I think the following (sole) warning is due to this?

> `Latexmk: Missing input file: 'thesis.syi' from line.
>   'No file thesis.syi.'
>   name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one`

I do not wish to drop into the shell to run `makeindex` because I appreciate the continuous compilation integration of latexmk from within my editor. How do I coax `latexmk` to produce this `syi` file?

Comment: What is the manual command to produce the syi file?

Comment: You need to substitute `gls-abr` and `glo-abr` with the relevant extensions (specified by `\newglossary[` *transcript extension* `]{` *type* `}{` *gls extension* `}{` *glo extension* `}`). In your case it seems that `syi` is the *gls extension* but you haven't provided any information about the *glo extension*.  (It's a good idea to also specify a transcript file as well in the `makeindex` call if you have multiple glossaries or an index to avoid a name clash.)